# How to implement thumb and fore finger interface

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, openframeworks

I am developing a simple multi touch table using only a projector and a web cam. I found out that i could use this [Thumb and fore finger interface technique](http://www.gizmowatch.com/entry/thumb-and-forefinger-interface-an-innovative-algorithm-solving-method/). but i don't have any clue of how to implement it. i think it can be implemented with OpenCV or OpenFrameworks and use with CCV. can anybody help me ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found something helpful [here](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~alexs/classes/2007_Fall_401/proposals/05_GestureRecognition.pdf) Thanks everyone.. and if you have any coding examples let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the [researcher's web site](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/awilson/) and download his recent papers about the subject. There the core parts of his technique should be explained.